# How to access fetched property in Objective-C 2.0 using Core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I'm new to IPhone development and I'm currently trying my hand at Core Data. I have a couple of entities that I've defined in my model. In one entity I have a fetched property. When I generate the Objective-C source files from my model, my entity that I defined with the fetched property does not have a property defined for the fetched property. Why? How do I access the fetched property?

More details in response to Tim:

- I have an entity named `Library` and another entity named `Book`.
- `Library` has a one to many relationship to `Book` (`Book` also has an inverse relationship).
- `Book` has a BOOL property called `isCheckedOut`.
- I defined a fetched property on `Library` called `fetchAllCheckedOutBooks`. The destination entity is `Book` and the predicate is `isCheckedOut == 1`.

Comment: It would help if we could know the destination entity and predicate you have set for the fetched property. Also, I assume you're having Xcode generate the source files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried using valueForKey: and passing in the name of your fetched property?  That's how I would expect it to work.  I would also expect that it would return an NSSet object, but that's easily verified by doing this:

```
id results = [myManagedObject valueForKey:@"fetchedPropertyName"];
NSLog(@"%@", [results className]);
```

Comment: -1 fetched properties return NSArray not NSSet

http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-SW7

A fetched property is represented by an array, not a set. The fetch request associated with the property can have a sort ordering, and thus the fetched property may be ordered.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, this is annoying....

Fetched properties are returned as an NSArray, so you just have to add it yourself:

//.h
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *fetchedPropertyName;

//.m
@dynamic fetchedPropertyName;

Answer (score 0):

yeah, really odd that Xcode doesn't include this when it generates the NSManagedObject subclass like it does for regular attributes and relationships